# CTRL+SHIFT+DOWN not working in Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> is not working in Excel 2007. I have unchecked:

Options → Advanced → Tools → Options → Transition Navigation Keys

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> is working fine. If I connect to an external keyboard then it is working fine.

Do you have any suggestions about what the problem could be?

Comment: sorry to ask this, but can you just confirm that the down button works?  Can you also confirm you don't have any keyboard mapping installed like autohotkey

Comment: Could you also confirm that you have tried to use this shortcut from different positions in the spreadsheet, and in different spreadsheets?

Comment: Hi Dave The down button works, i can use the down button to move down field by field but when I use CTRL+SHIFT+DOWN it is not working

Comment: Hi Garrulinae , I have tried in different positions it is not working, checked the scroll on/off possibilities still not working

Comment: Does CTRL+DOWN (without Shift) function normally?

Comment: CTRL+DOWN is working fine.

Comment: I have turned off the sticky keys in control panel.

Comment: I have tried virutal Key board with Echo User's Keystrokes, when i press SHIFT+CTRL+DOWN it doesnot read the down arrow

Comment: Hi Senthil,
Please, try to press `right` Ctrl+ `right` Shift + Down
Also, try to press Ctrl+Shift+Down in any Word document (the whole paragraph should be selected).

Comment: Hi Alex Ctrl+shirt+down arrow is not working in word also. Ctrl+shift+up arrow is working fine in word and excel